# How to remove spaces at start and end of a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have an imported CSV in my spreadsheet. When I run a refresh macro it adds a space to the beginning and end of each cell.

I'm trying to remedy it by having the same macro trim all the spaces at the start and end of a cell (not in between).

Doing it on a single cell works without issue

```
Range("F10").Value = Trim(Range("F10").Value)
```

In a range it doesn't do anything, no error message, just no reaction

```
Dim cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range
Set areaToTrim = Sheet1.Range("A6:J10")
For Each cell In areaToTrim
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

In reality, I don't want it to be A6 to J10, I just put this in to see if it worked with a range. I want it to be A6 to J last row. So I wanted my final code to be

```
Dim lastrowindex As Long
lastrowindex = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim db_range_start As String
Dim db_range_end As String

db_range_start = "A6"
db_range_end = "J" & lastrowindex
db_range_region = db_range_start & ":" & db_range_end

Dim db_range As Range
Set db_range = Range(db_range_region)

Dim cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range
Set areaToTrim = Sheet1.Range(db_range)
For Each cell In areaToTrim
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

But this throws a

> Method Value of object Range failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following, just took your code and simplified it, as you declared `db_range` as a Range and then tried to use it to specify the range using `Sheet1.Range(db_range)` which would take a string instead of a Range:

```
Sub Trim_Range()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim c As Range
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In ws.Range("A6:J" & LastRow)
    c.Value = Trim(c.Value)
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Any idea why the refreshing of the imported data would be adding spaces? I'm puzzled

Comment: @samrb that would really depend on how you are importing the data, not sure though to be honest...